# How to run test for 1 hr and make exactly x amount of requests

Tags: jmeter

I am struggling with how to configure my jmeter test to run for a specific amount of time.

I am using the access log sampler. I am configuring the group threads and the loop count. But it seems if I increase the group threads, the amount will still launch a request in 1 seconds. If I increase the loop count...it still end up running in a seconds.

I know the amount of request I need per second. I used this as the group threads. If I can make the group thread run per second then my problem is solved, then I can use the loop count to repeat 3600 times to make an hour...but this does not seem o be the case. The amount requests specified via the group threads run in less than a second!...

How do I configure the tests so that it runs in say 1 hr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you look at JMeter's [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you will see `Specify thread lifetime` input:

   [image]

   this is how you can control for how long JMeter threads are allowed to run
2. If you want to send specific amount of requests during this hour consider using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer), but be aware of the following:

   - Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** JMeter threads to limit the throughput (number of requests per minute) to the given value
   - JMeter must be able to "fire" requests fast enough so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
   - Your application must be able to respond fast enough because JMeter waits for previous request to finish prior to starting a new one so if your application is too slow you cannot force it to respond faster